# Prove that $ \lim_{h\to0}\intop_{a}^{b}|f\left(x+h\right)-f\left(x\right)|dx=0 $

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

let $ f $ be integrable function in the interval $ [a-\varepsilon,b+\varepsilon] $ for $ \varepsilon>0 $

and let $ -\varepsilon<h<\varepsilon $.
prove that :

$ \lim_{h\to0}\intop_{a}^{b}|f\left(x+h\right)-f\left(x\right)|dx=0 $

Here's what I tried:

I've proved that $ \intop_{a}^{b}f\left(x+h\right)dx=\intop_{a+h}^{b+h}f\left(x\right)dx $

And then I proved that $ \lim_{h\to0}\intop_{a}^{b}\left(f\left(x+h\right)-f\left(x\right)\right)dx=0 $

But I'm not sure how to make the connection between the previous things I've proved to this statement.

Note: we haven't learned in class Lebesgue integral so we can only use Riemann integral in the proof.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $f$ is integrable in $[a-1,b+1]$, then prove that $\lim \limits_{h\to 0} \ \int_{a}^{b}|f(x+h)-f(x)| ~ dx=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85474/if-f-is-integrable-in-a-1-b1-then-prove-that-lim-limits-h-to-0-i)

Comment: If $f$ is Riemman integrable, then $f$ is bounded.

Comment: try to show that any primitive of an integrable function is a continuous function, hence the result